# Pre-defined variable is empty in when creating VSTS release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Service Fabric project set up with CD in VSTS. The CD process have been set up from the CD wizard in visual studio. So far so good but when the release is made I'm not getting any value from the [pre-defined variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/index#numbering) called `Build.DefinitionName` that I use for naming the releases.

This is how my Release name is configured: `$(Build.DefinitionName)-$(date:yyyyMM).$(rev:r)`

If we look in the release log there is no value for the variables:

```
[BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME] --> []
[RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_{Primary artifact alias}*_DEFINITIONNAME] --> []
```

*This value is populated correctly.

And according to the docs of primary artifact variables the two variables above should be the same.

As a result of this my releases are named *$(Build.DefinitionName)-201702.7*

If I use `Build.BuildNumber` instead. I get the correct value.

How can I get the variables populated?

---

**Update**

When creating the Build and Release definitions manually the `$(Build.DefinitionName)` gets populated correctly on the Release side. But the problem seems to appear when you use the [CD wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hDnI.png) from Visual Studio. I might be missing something but the settings of the Build Definition are identical. Or there is some funky stuff going on with the CD wizard.

Comment: Are you trying to pass variables to release management from the build process?

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. (release name: $(Build.DefinitionName)-$(date:yyyyMM).$(rev:r), then the result is ClassTestVNext-201702.3) Can you reproduce this issue with the new build and release definition? What's the detail log of release?

Comment: @MrHinsh Yes exactly. By reading the documentation I was under the impression that this should work out of the box.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I just tried setting up a new build and release definition manually. I could not reproduce the error either. But when I used the CD Wizard from Visual Studio I got the same error again. Compared allt he settings and they are Identical in the build definition. So my workaround would be creating my definitions manually.

Comment: What're steps of using the CD wizard from visual studio?

Comment: @starain-MSFT You point out the team project, repository, agent, sf cluster and naming of the build and release definitions. It is just adding the default Service Fabric build and release definitions for you.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that issue too. So the solution is create the release definition manually, I post an answer that you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create the release definition manually on web access and set Continuous Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

On the build number is passed from Build to a release, there is no out of the box way to pass more variables between build and release.

However I write a ser of build tasks to do this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration

It consists of two tasks, the first saves the specified variables to a json file, which you should put in the build output.

The second restores the variables you want. Especially useful if you have multiple source build for your release.